# How to count the number of customer per month in R?

Tags: r

So I have a table of customers with the respective date as below:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-04-17 |
| 4 | 2019-05-12 |
| 1 | 2019-04-25 |
| 2 | 2019-05-19 |

I just want to count how many Customer is there for each month-year like below:

| Month-Year | Count of Customer |
| --- | --- |
| Apr-19 | 2 |
| May-19 | 2 |

EDIT:
Sorry but I think my Question should be clearer.
The same customer can appear more than once in a month and would be counted as 2 customer for the same month. I would basically like to find the number of transaction per month based on customer id.

My assumed approach would be to first change the date into a month-year format? And then I count each customer and grouped it for each month? but I am not sure how to do this in R. Thank you!

Comment: Please make your question reproducible by pasting a sample of your data: use `dput(head(your_data_sample, n))` where `n` is enough data to demonstrate the problem. This makes it easier for others to copy the data to test and verify solutions.

Comment: As Peter said: Post your data reproducibly as in https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Also: If your question is about time and date look into the `lubridate` package, which defines usefull functions such as `month` and `year`. See the cheatsheet here: https://evoldyn.gitlab.io/evomics-2018/ref-sheets/R_lubridate.pdf use `paste` on their outcomes and then `aggregate`.

Comment: Is `CRN` customer id? Does a customer occur only once in a month? It is helpful to compare the answer if your expected output matches your input dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `zoo::as.yearmon`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     count(Date = zoo::as.yearmon(Date))
      Date n
1 Apr 2019 2
2 May 2019 2
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 4L, 1L, 2L), Date = c("2019-04-17", 
"2019-05-12", "2019-04-25", "2019-05-19")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `count` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% count(Month_Year = format(as.Date(Date), '%b-%y'))

#  Month_Year n
#1     Apr-19 2
#2     May-19 2
```

Or `table` in base R -

```
table(format(as.Date(df$Date), '%b-%y'))

#Apr-19 May-19 
#     2      2
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 4L, 1L, 2L), Date = c("2019-04-17", 
"2019-05-12", "2019-04-25", "2019-05-19")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```